# How do I create an Azure OpenAI deployment using GPT-4 if my model options are only GPT-35-turbo*?

Tags: azure, openai-api, azure-openai, gpt-4

I am able to create deployments using gpt-35-turbo* models. I want to create a gpt-4 deployment, but I don't see those models available in my subscription. How do I find the gpt-4 models?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

> How do I find the gpt-4 models?

Based on the documentation [`here`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/ai-services/openai/concepts/models#gpt-4-and-gpt-4-turbo-preview-models), GPT-4 models are not available in all the regions:

[image]

That could be the reason why you are not seeing those models.

I would recommend checking the region where these models are available ([link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/ai-services/openai/concepts/models#gpt-4-and-gpt-4-turbo-preview-model-availability)) and create your Azure OpenAI service in that region in order to use GPT-4 models.